# Array of labels event action

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I'm currently trying to add a specific action to an array of labels but the variables are kept only between the `{}`.

```
_arr[i].Click += (a, b) => {  
     z++;

     numarfinal = Convert.ToString(z);
     MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(numarfinal));
};
```

Outside `{}` neither  variable `z` nor `numarfinal` has changed but the `MessageBox.Show` reports that their parameters have changed.

Here is the whole function:

```
Label[] _arr = new Label[20];
Label[] _dinamic = new Label[20];
private static Random _r = new Random();
string numarfinal ;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int z=0;
    int limita = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
    limita = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    if (limita > 20)
        textBox1.Text = "Do sth";

    int randomnumber = _r.Next(20);


    for(int i=0;i<limita;i++)
    {
        do
        {
                randomnumber = _r.Next(20);
        } while (randomnumber==0);

        _arr[i] = new Label();

        _arr[i].Click += (a, b) =>
        {                                   
            z++;
            numarfinal= Convert.ToString(z);                                  
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(numarfinal));                            
        };

    _arr[i ].Text = Convert.ToString(randomnumber);
    _arr[i ].Size = new Size(50,50);
    _arr[i ].Location = new Point(55*i,60);
            testlabel.Text = Convert.ToString(numarfinal); // the label value remain nothing  (numarfinal's initial value)


    this.Controls.Add(_arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: need more code, where are z and numarfinal declared?

Comment: So you have global variables `z` and `numarfinal`, you change them in the handler, you can see the change, and then the variables are rolled back to their previous values?

Comment: inside the private  `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` `z` is type int and `numarfinal` is a string. Also the code I've provided earlier is in the same function.

Comment: could you post the whole button1_click ?

Comment: @Fredou done. as you can see in the last part of the code I transfer the `numarfinal` value to `testlabel` but the label text remains nothing.

Comment: so what you want it to do is put the # on the label and when you click on it to show a messagebox that say this # ?

Comment: no, in the first part I create a number of labels with a random number then when the users click on any of these labels the program should make another label down with the number from the specific label but the problem is that I can't pass the value of z outside the {} from label click. To develop my program I need this basic thing to have that value `z` or `numarfinal`. So any idea why the variables are rolled back to their previous values ?

Comment: @GSerg yes the variables are rolled back to their previous values. I have no idea how to keep their values.

Comment: Are you aware that the line `testlabel.Text =...` is NOT going to be called each time your labels are clicked? Your code is a bit hard to follow but from your comment "label text remains nothing" makes me think you are under the impression that that line will be reached whenever your label `Click` delegate is called (it will not but rather that line will only be reached when button1 is clicked).

Comment: @blins Yes, I know that but that line is called once and it doesn't change to 0 or any number it remains null if I assign `numarfinal` and if I assign `z` value it will remain 0, `z` default value. So actually both `numarfinal` and `z` will roll back to their default values. One more thing, if I move the `testlabel.Text = Convert.ToString(numarfinal);` inside the .Click{} it will work but outside it doesn't.

Comment: Clicking button1 will never cause the line `numarfinal = Convert.ToString(z);` to be reached.

Comment: I see, that is logical that's why it works when it is inside the .Click{}; You can add that to answer.Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set `testlabel.Text` once, while the value of `numarfinal` is still null. When one of the labels is clicked and its event handler is executed, the value of `numarfinal` is changed, but the value of `testlabel.Text` isn't.

One way to fix that is to simply set `testlabel.Text` in the event handler lambda:

```
_arr[i].Click += (a, b) =>
{
    z++;
    numarfinal = Convert.ToString(z);
    testlabel.Text = numarfinal;
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(numarfinal));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The z value is being changed in the click events of the labels. If you want to see the change in your testlabel you should change its text "in the click events". If you want to change numarfinal every time you add a label you should put your code out of click events and if you want numarfinal change every time you click on a label your code should be were it already is.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking button1 will never cause the line `numarfinal = Convert.ToString(z);` to be reached because your are only **attaching** the delegate there. When you assign the delegate with `(a, b) => {...}`, the code within the `{}` is not called until the respective event is actually raised (i.e., clicking the respective label).